# What is the UK-US tax treaty information relevant to IRS form W-8BEN for a private investor?

Tags: united-states, taxes, united-kingdom, irs, shares

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf
I am looking to start buying shares in US companies, through brokerage firm 212. I need to fill in the above form to do that. What do I need to put in for part 2 Claim of Tax Treaty Benefits? I've marked the blanks with ???

> 9 I certify that the beneficial owner is a resident of UNITED KINGDOM
> within the meaning of the income tax treaty between the United States
> and that country.
>
> 10 Special rates and conditions (if applicable—see
> instructions): The beneficial owner is claiming the provisions of
> Article and paragraph **???** of the treaty identified on line 9 above to
> claim a **???** % rate of withholding on (specify type of income): **???**.
>
> Explain the additional conditions in the Article and paragraph the
> beneficial owner meets to be eligible for the rate of withholding: **???**

Comment: The IRS is pretty good about providing instructions for each of their forms. You may find [this document](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw8ben.pdf) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be NOTHING; in **specific instructions** under **Line 10**:

> Line 10 must be used only if you are claiming treaty benefits that
> require that you meet conditions not covered by the representations
> you make on line 9 and Part III. For example, persons claiming treaty
> benefits on royalties must complete this line if the treaty contains
> different withholding rates for different types of royalties. However,
> this line should always be completed by foreign students and
> researchers claiming treaty benefits.
>
> See Scholarship and fellowship grants, later, for more information.
> This line is generally not applicable to treaty benefits under an
> interest or dividends (other than dividends subject to a preferential
> rate based on ownership) article of a treaty.