W-8BEN - Claim tax treaty benefits of W8-BEN for dividends and capital gains for a resident Indian
I have been to USA for 9 years and returned back to India last year. I hold some stocks in brokerage account in USA and I understand that I am required to submit W-8BEN to my broker for year 2024.

I am not sure what I should fill out in the following section of W-8BEN. Can someone please help?


Special rates and conditions (if applicable—see instructions): The
beneficial owner is claiming the provisions of Article and paragraph
of the treaty identified on line 9 above to claim a _____ % rate of
withholding on (specify type of income):
. Explain the additional conditions in the Article and paragraph the
beneficial owner meets to be eligible for the rate of withholding:


Under which section does the capital gains and dividends received from stocks comes in https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/india.pdf ?

Do I need to send separate W-8BEN forms for the capital gains and
dividends ?



Dividends are article 10 as clearly stated at the beginning of the document you link, and you get a 25% rate. US does not tax nonresident aliens on capital gain unless you are operating a US trade or business or they are on real property or publicly-traded partnerships neither of which you mentioned, so you don't need any form for that. You don't need line ten because there are no additional conditions on the 25% dividend rate. See https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125784/ (also India) and https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/94509/ (UK).

thanks @dave_thompson_085, appreciated !
